# Can you color a planar graph given a coloring of its triangulation?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Several proofs of the four color theorem (or failed attempts) start with something like "We need only consider triangulations, because every simple planar graph is contained in a triangulation".

On an intuitive level, it makes sense. The triangulation is maximally connected. Since it has more edges than the original graph, it is more difficult to find a proper coloring.  By solving a harder problem, you're solving the easier problem for free.  However, this still seems like an assumption to me.

Suppose I have a simple planar graph G and a triangulation of G called G'.  Given a proper face coloring of G', how do I construct a proper face coloring of G?

Comment: If $G'$ and $G$ have the same set of vertices and every edge of $G$ is also an edge of $G'$ then a proper coloring of $G'$ is a proper coloring of $G$.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more precise, thanks. The 4CT is about face coloring, not vertex coloring.

Comment: I think you're mis-summarizing the basic proof strategy for the 4CT. The point is that first we observe via planar duality that coloring faces of planar graphs is equivalent to coloring vertices of (dual) planar graphs. Thus the 4CT is the statement that every planar graph has a proper vertex coloring with 4 colors. Then we can assume that the plane graph (i.e., with a fixed embedding into the plane) we are trying to vertex color is triangulated, because addition of edges only makes coloring harder. See e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Summary_of_proof_ideas.

Comment: Ah, thanks Sam Hopkins.  I suppose my question could still be interesting outside the context of the 4CT, but you're totally right.  Doh!

Comment: Since every face of $G'$ borders only $3$ others, a proper face coloring of $G'$ with $4$ colors is trivial; the greedy coloring algorithm works fine. Nothing that easy is going to help you get a proper face coloring of an arbitrary planar graph $G$ with $4$ colors.

Comment: Actually most triangulated graphs have a proper face coloring with $3$ colors because of Brooks' theorem.